# Is it possible to access EntityTypeConfiguration from DbModelBuilder directly from DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I was wondering if it's possible to read at runtime the configuration information I add in the `OnModelCreating` method of my `Dbcontext`.

The idea is that I could store a value I need further in this configuration, and retrieve it later.